# Power BI: Make a line chart continuous when source contains null values (handle missing values)

Tags: graph, charts, powerbi, dax

This question spinned off a question I posted earlier;
[Custom x-axis values in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360243/custom-x-axis-values-in-power-bi)

Suppose the following data set:

[image]

Focus on the second and third row. How can I make the line in corresponding graph hereunder be continuous and not stop in the middle?

[image]

In Excel I used to solve this problem by applying NA() in a formula generating data for the graph. Is there a similar solution using DAX perhaps?

Comment: I think it will only do this if you use a continuous x-axis rather than a categorical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The short version:*

---

## **What you should do:**

[Unleash python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-using-python-on-multiple-tables-in-the-query-editor/51947461#51947461) and after following the steps there, insert this script (dont't worry, I've added some details here as well):

```
import pandas as pd

# retrieve index column
index = dataset[['YearWeek_txt']]

# subset input data for further calculations
dataset2 = dataset[['1', '2']]

# handle missing values
dataset2 = dataset2.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Then you will be able to set it up like this:

[image]

## **Why you should do it:**

For built-in options, these are your choices as far as I know:

**1.** Categorical YearMonth and categorical x-axis does not work

[image]

**2.** Categorical YearMonth and continuous x-axis does not work

[image]

**3.** Numerical YearMonth and categorical x-axis does not work

[image]

**4.** Numerical YearMonth and continuous x-axis does not work

[image]

---

*The details, starting with why built-in approaches fail:*

---

**1.** Categorical YearMonth and categorical x-axis

I've used the following dataset that resembles the screenshot of your table:

```
YearWeek   1     2
201603     2.37  2.83
201606           2.55
201607     2.98 
201611     2.33  2.47
201615     2.14  2.97
201619     2.15  2.02
201623     2.33  2.8
201627     3.04  2.57
201631     2.95  2.98
201635     3.08  2.16
201639     2.50  2.42
201643     3.07  3.02
201647     2.19  2.37
201651     2.38  2.65
201703     2.50  3.02
201711     2.10  2
201715     2.76  3.04
```

And NO, I didn't bother manually copying ALL your data. Just your YearWeek series. The rest are random numbers between 2 and 3.

Then I set the data up as numerical for 1 and 2, and YearWeek aa type text in the Power Query Editor:

[image]

So this is the original setup with a table and chart like yours:

[image]

The data is sorted descending by YearWeek_txt:

[image]

And the x-axis is set up as`Categorical`:

[image]

**Conclusion:** *Fail*

---

**2.** Categorical YearMonth and numercial x-axis

With the same setup as above, you can try to change the x-axis type to `Continuous`:

[image]

But as you'll see, it just flips right back to 'Categorical', presumably because the type of YearWeek is `text`.

**Conclusion:** *Fail*

---

**3.** Numerical YearMonth and categorical x-axis

I've duplicated the original setup so that I've got two tables Categorical and Numerical where the type of YearWeek are `text` and `integer`, respectively:

[image]

So numerical YearMonth and categorical x-axis still gives you this:

[image]

**Conclusion:** *Fail*

---

**4.** Numerical YearMonth and continuous x-axis does not work

But *now*, with the same setup as above, you are able to change the x-axis type to `Continuous`:

[image]

And you'll end up with this:

[image]

**Conclusion:** *LOL*

---

## And now, Python:

---

In the `Power Query Editor`, activate the `Categorical` table, select `Transform > Run Python Script` and insert the following snippet in the Run `Python Script Editor`:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

import pandas as pd

# retrieve index column
index = dataset[['YearWeek_txt']]

# subset input data for further calculations
dataset2 = dataset[['1', '2']]

# handle missing values
dataset2 = dataset2.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Click `OK` and click `Table` next to `dataset2` here:

[image]

And you'll get this (make sure that the column data types are correct):

[image]

As you can see, no more missing values. `dataset2 = dataset2.fillna(method='ffill')` has replaced all missing values with the preceding value in both columns.

Click Close&Apply to get back to the Desktop, and enjoy your table and chart with no more missing values:

[image]

**Conclusion:** *Python is cool*

---

**End note:**

There are a lot of details that can go wrong here with decimal points, data types and so on. Let me know how things work out for you and I'll have a look at it again if it doesn't work on your end.

Comment: Sorry, insanely late response; this works! (sure no surprises for you there). It's a bit of a leap of faith jumping into Python. Surely I trust it to be cool, but now see this is also solid after a while. Thanks!

Comment: @Sambo No problem! Glad it worked for you. And python is a breeze compared to DAX =)