# Power BI: How to use Python with multiple tables in the Power Query Editor?

Tags: python, powerbi

How can you create a new table with a Python script that uses two existing tables as input? For example by performing a `left join` using [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)?

**Some details:**

Using `Home > Edit queries` you can utilize Python under `Transform > Run Python Script`. This opens a `Run Python Script` dialog box where your're told that `'#dataset'  holds the input data for this script`. And you'll find the same phrase if you just click `OK` and look at the formula bar:

`= Python.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script#(lf)",[dataset=#"Changed Type"])`

This also adds a new step under `Applied Steps` called `Run Python script` where you can edit the Python script by clicking the gear symbol on the right:

[image]

***How can you change that setup to reference more than one table?***

---

**Sample data**

Here are two tables that can be stored as CSV files and loaded using `Home > Get Data > Text/CSV`

**Table1**

```
Date,Value1
2108-10-12,1
2108-10-13,2
2108-10-14,3
2108-10-15,4
2108-10-16,5
```

**Table2**

```
Date,Value2
2108-10-12,10
2108-10-13,11
2108-10-14,12
2108-10-15,13
2108-10-16,14
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is the same challenge that has been described for R scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897796/operations-on-multiple-tables-datasets-with-edit-queries-and-r-in-power-bi). That setup should work for Python too. However, I've found that that approach has one drawback: It stores the new joined or calculated table as an edited version of one of the previous tables. The following suggestion will demonstrate how you can produce a completely new calculated table without altering the input tables (except changing the data type of the Date columns from `Date` to `Text` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929420/python-script-in-power-bi-returns-date-as-microsoft-oledb-date).)

**Short answer:**

In the `Power Query editor`, follow these steps:

1. Change the data type of the `Date columns` in both columns to `Text`.
2. Click `Enter Data`. *Only* click `OK`.
3. Activate the new `Table3` and use `Transform > Run Python Script`. *Only* click `OK`.
4. Activate the formula bar and replace what's in it with `= Python.Execute("# Python:",[df1=Table1, df2=Table2])`. Click `Enter`.
5. If you're prompted to do so, click `Edit Permission` and `Run` in the next step.
6. Under `Applied Steps`, in the new step named `Run Python Script`, click the gear icon to open the `Run Python Script` editor.
7. Insert the snippet below and click `OK`.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = ['Date'])
df3['Value3'] = df1['Value1']*df2['Value2']
```

Next to `df3`, click `Table`, and that's it:

[image]

**The details:**

The list above will have to be followed very carefully to get things working. So here are all of the dirty little details:

**1.** Load the tables as CSV files in Power BI Desktop using `Get Data`.

**2.** Click  `Edit Queries`.

**3.** In `Table1`, Click the symbol next to the `Date column`, select `Text` and click `Replace Current`

[image]

**4.** Do the same for `Table2`

**5.** On the `Home` tab, click `Enter Data`

**6.** In the appearing box, do nothing else than clicking `OK`.

[image]

**7.** This will insert an empty table named `Table3` under `Queries`, and that's exactly what we want:

[image]

**8.** Go to the `Transform` tab and click `Run Python Script`:

[image]

**9.** This opens the `Run Python Script` editor. And you *can* start writing you scripts right here, but that will make things unnecessarily complicated in the next steps. So do nothing but click `OK`:

[image]

**10.** In the formula bar you will se the formula `= Python.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script#(lf)",[dataset=#"Changed Type"])`. And notice that you've got a new step under Applied Steps named `Run Python Script`:

[image]

**11.** There are several interesting details in the screenshot above, but first we're going to break down the arguments of the function `= Python.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script#(lf)",[dataset=#"Changed Type"])`.

The part `"# 'dataset'" holds the input data for this script#(lf)"` simply inserts the comment that you can see in the `Python Script Editor`. So it's not important, but you can't just leave it blank either. I like to use something shorter like `"# Python:"`.

The part `[dataset=#"Changed Type"]` is a pointer to the empty `Table3` in the state that it is under `Changed Type`. So if the last thing that you do before inserting a Python Script is something else than changing data types, this part will look different. The table is then made available in your python script using `dataset` as a pandas data frame. With this in mind, we can make som very useful changes to the formula:

**12.** Change the formula bar to `= Python.Execute("# Python:",[df1=Table1, df2=Table2])` and hit `Enter`. This will make `Table1` and `Table2` available for your Python scripts as two pandas dataframes named `df1` and `df2`, respectively.

**13.** Click the gear (or is it a flower?) icon next to `Run Python script` under `Applied Steps`:

[image]

**14.** Insert the following snippet:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = ['Date'])
df3['Value3'] = df1['Value1']*df2['Value2']
```

This will join `df1` and `df2` on the `Date column`, and insert a new calculated column named `Value3`. Not too fancy, but with this setup you can do *anything* you want with your data in the world of Power BI and with the power of Python.

[image]

**15.** Click `OK` and you'll se this:

[image]

You'll see `df3` listed under the input dataframes `df1` and `df2` in the blue square. If you've assigned any other dataframes as a step in your calculations in the Python script, they will be listed here too. In order to turn it into an accessible table for Power BI, just click `Table` as indicated by the green arrow.

**16.** And that's it:

[image]

Note that the data type of the `Date column` is set to `Date` by default, but you can change that to `Text` as explained earlier.

Click `Home > Close&Apply` to exit the `Power Query Editor` and go back to where it all started in Power BI Desktop.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks mate, only question is how does this execute in the cloud? or can it execute in the cloud ? say when my data refreshes will the python script also run ? if so where does it run from? as at the moment its running from my local machine (can't even use a virtual env.. sad face)

Comment: @Datanovice You're certainly asking the right questions!!! The flexibility of Python still seems to be very limited in PowerBI. When I started messing around with it in PowerBI, what you're asking was certainly not possible. To be honest, I'm no sure how things are coming along nowadays...

Comment: I see, then only in desktop then - that makes sense (and makes any sort of ETL useless), but good for one time hits or POC before moving onto to databricks or something else.

Comment: @Datanovice Sometimes I just love to be wrong!! [Python visualizations in Power BI Service](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/python-visualizations-in-power-bi-service/)

Comment: I have followed the steps laid out here but when I reach step 12(changing the formula bar to access different datasets) I get the following error: "Formula.Firewall: Query 'Table1' (step 'Run Python script') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.". Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: 2@AJHello I'll see if I can find the time to reproduce the error sometime tonight. Don't hesitate to remind me if I forget.

Comment: @vestland thank you. Just in case there is confusion by the way, in the error message that I posted, it references 'Table1'. 'Table1' in my case is the empty table that I created after following step 6.

Comment: @AJHello This seems to be a known issue, and has got very little to do with the approach I've described here. Take a look [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Formula-Firewall-Query-references-other-queries-so-it-may-not/m-p/18637#M5539)

Comment: @AJHello One way is to ignore privacy levels. have a look here : https://sqlitybi.com/formula-firewall-error-referencing-queries-r-python-scripts/?doing_wp_cron=1607704049.9783151149749755859375

Comment: I am getting this error -- ```Formula.Firewall: Query 'Table' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.``` @vestland

Answer (score 8):

You can create a Blank Query and replace its contents in Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Python.Execute("# Python:#(lf)",[df1=Table1, df2=Table2])
in
    Source
```

After you can click on the gear by the Source to add your python code where you can use df1 and df2.

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: @srodriguex I am getting this error -- ```Formula.Firewall: Query 'Table' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.```

Comment: @derikS4M1 you have to disable the Privacy Levels check from the option of the current file (File --> Options and settings --> Options --> [CURRENT FILE / Privacy] --> Ignore the Privacy Levels and potentially improve performance). Then refresh your report.