# Reverse a string using DAX

Tags: dax

I'd like to create a calculated column that reverses the string in an existing column. For example, if I have the following table

```
ID  String
----------
1   Alpha
2   Beta
3   Gamma
```

I'd like to get this:

```
ID  String  Reverse
-------------------
1   Alpha   ahplA
2   Beta    ateB
3   Gamma   ammaG
```

I know how to use `SEARCH`, `FIND`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `MID`, `SUBSTITUTE`, `REPLACE`, `REPT`, `LEN` etc. but can't seem to get them to do what I want.

---

I'm providing one possible solution below, but I'm interested in other possibilities as well.

Answer (score 1):

May not be pretty, but one approach to this is to generate an index, reverse it, and then concatenate each character by the reversed index:

```
Reverse =
    CONCATENATEX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, LEN ( Table1[String] ) ),
            "Index", LEN ( Table1[String] ) - [Value] + 1
        ),
        MID ( Table1[String], [Index], 1 )
    )
```

For the string `Alpha`, which has 5 characters, this generates the following table:

```
Value  Index = 5 - Value + 1
----------------------------
 1      5
 2      4
 3      3
 4      2
 5      1
```

Now for each row in this table, the `MID` function picks the character in the `Index` position:

```
Value  Index  MID("Alpha", Index, 1)
------------------------------------
 1      5      a
 2      4      h
 3      3      p
 4      2      l
 5      1      A
```

The `CONCATENATEX` function takes this table and concatenates the third column to get `ahplA`.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for `DAX` specifically. But since you're also saying that you're looking for other possibilities than the solution you've provided yourself, I feel compelled to mention a [very elegant approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) using [Python in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-using-python-on-multiple-tables-in-the-query-editor/51947461#51947461):

```
#In:
'StackOverflow'[::-1]

#Out:
'wolfrevOkcatS'
```

That's it!