# Percentage calculation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the below table,

```
Branch      Status
Chennai       unattended
Chennai       closed
Chennai       NotApplicable
Coimbatore    Assigned
Coimbatore    NotApplicable
Coimbatore    open
Coimbatore    open
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of status based on branch.
Also I want to the "CARD Visualization" in Power BI.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is your question? What aspect are you struggling with? The logic? The formula? Post what you have tried.

Comment: @sarankumar, did my suggestion solve your problems? If it did, would you consider marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that what you're really looking for here is a [cross tab](https://www.researchoptimus.com/article/cross-tab.php), so that you go from this:

```
Branch,Status
Chennai,unattended
Chennai,closed
Chennai,NotApplicable
Coimbatore,Assigned
Coimbatore,NotApplicable
Coimbatore,open
Coimbatore,open
```

To this:

```
Branch      Assigned    NotApplicable   closed  open    unattended
Chennai     0           1               1       0       1
Coimbatore  1           1               0       2       0
```

And then do the rest of the calculations from there. Unfortunately I can't find a way to do it with `DAX`. But you *can* do it if you're willing to use a [Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-using-python-on-multiple-tables-in-the-query-editor/51947461#51947461) in the Query Editor. You'll get what you need If you follow the steps in the linked post. Here are some details:

**1.** Copy the dataset I provided with comma as columns separator. Go to `Edit Queries > Enter Data`, paste the data, Click `Undo Headers > OK`, select the column and split it on `,` and click `Use First Row as Headers` so that you end up with this:

[image]

**2.** Go to Transform > Run Python Script an insert this snippet:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd
crosstab = pd.crosstab(dataset.Branch, dataset.Status).reset_index()
```

**3.** Click `Table` next to crosstab

[image]

**4.** Make sure that you have this and Click `Home > Close&Apply`

[image]

Insert a `Matrix visualization` in Power BI Dekstop. It can *not* be a table since that does not have the same flexiblity with regards to what we're going to do next.

**5.** Select the `Branch` column first, and the other columns in any order you want:

[image]

**6.** Remove ``Total` column

[image]

**7.** For all other columns than Branch, select Show value as > Percent of column total

[image]

**8.** And note that you can remove those pesky prefixes manually in the table settings:

[image]

**9.** There you go:

[image]

**10** And you probably know this, but you can insert a slicer as well to subset your table as you please:

[image]