# Use python in Power BI queried

Tags: python, powerbi

I have two tables in my Power BI (both made from append queries) and I need to compare them to create my report. I have a script in Python that works in the coding environment but, when trying to use it in Power BI, I have been unable to reference the tables in my scrip. I keep getting the same error that does not recognise them. I tried following the guidance in this post and it did not work.

[Power BI: How to use Python with multiple tables in the Power Query Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-how-to-use-python-with-multiple-tables-in-the-power-query-editor)

I have been unable to find any other example of how to do it. Do you have any guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What failed when you tried following the mentioned guide?

Comment: Hi, not sure what failed. I got it solved and as I tried many things I am not sure which one was the solution... thank you very much for helping. I used your link as a guidance and I think it was a very good answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power BI: How to use Python with multiple tables in the Power Query Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-how-to-use-python-with-multiple-tables-in-the-power-query-editor)

Comment: Yes, it did! Thank you for you post. Everything I found links to it