# Cyclic reference error while joining two tables in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to test out the joining of two tables using python script and same data from  following the link below

[Power BI: How to use Python with multiple tables in the Power Query Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-how-to-use-python-with-multiple-tables-in-the-power-query-editor)

However, I keep getting cyclic reference error.
How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Dont those instructions seem to indicate using  Source= Python.Execute("# Python:", ... instead of what you are doing?

Comment: It does not matter, as its just a comment. I tried using both syntax as well but no luck

Comment: You can't reference in Table1 -> Step Run Python Script  to Table1; This produces an infinity loop. Do this as new query/table

Comment: I will try this