# Power BI: How to use Python to access multiple tables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi

I already read this post before:
[Power BI: How to use Python with multiple tables in the Power Query Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-how-to-use-python-with-multiple-tables-in-the-power-query-editor)

I'd like to do something like this inside PBI:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

proc = cad_processo
moeda = tab_moeda_data

def name_of_the_function(proc, moeda):
   df = code...
   return df
```

Now I'll explain more in-depth what I'm doing:

I'm in a table called **cad_processo**, I need to apply a very complex function to create a column in **cad_processo**, but in order to create this new column, I need another table called tab_moeda_data.

I tried what was explained in the post I quoted before, but I wasn't able to achieve nothing so far.

In theory it's simple, import 2 tables and apply a function to create a new column, but I'm not being able to import this second table (tab_moeda_data) into the cad_processo to apply the function.

[image]

*I know that cad_processo is called dataset in this case
I only need to import another table (tab_moeda_data) to apply the function, that's it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that the UI doesn't support, so you have to use the Advanced Editor.

But you can simply pass additional Tables to Python.Execute, eg

```
MainTable = ...,
RunPythonscript = Python.Execute(pythonScript,[dataset=MainTable, otherTable=OtherTable]),
```

And they will be available as additional pandas DataFrames in your script.